# Ruby on Rails типа селекторов в Jquery, но в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dom, css-selectors

Друзья, помогите, начал изучать Рельсы да и сам Руби.

Хочу создать программку.
Как обрашаться к элементам дом?
То есть как в Jquery

```
$('#id').click(function(){$('#id').html('Привет');});
```

Как такое исполнить на руби?
Если можно, дайте код.
Пока подключаю `'webrick'`.
Наверное, это вам стоит знать.

Дайте указание, что искать в гугле,
чтобы почитать про методы типа html, click, hide и т.д.,
а лучше ссылку на список таких методов.

И есть ли что-то более удобное, чем webrick, 
для работы с HTML?

Вот моя программа
индекс файл:
http://clip2net.com/s/j3HZh4
сервер:
http://clip2net.com/s/j3HTTr

Очень буду признателен за ответы.
Хочу хорошенько обосноваться тут на форуме.

Comment: Блоги рубистов читай :)

Comment: А как вы эту задачу решили бы на ПХП?

Answer (score 1):

Вам стоит разобраться в разнице между языками, исполняемыми на стороне клиента (Javascript) и исполняемыми на стороне сервера (Ruby).

То, что вы хотите, делается на Яваскрипте.

webrick - это такой вебсервер для отладки приложений  на Рельсах (грубо говоря).

Comment: Ну, вы поняли чего я хочу добиться?  
Можете мне написать код?  
Мне бы начать что-то делать, практика...
Дальше бы потихоньку развивался.  
Такое возможно только на HTML и Рельсах?
И хорошо ли это?

Разработка веб-приложений только на Рельсах и HTML не возможно?

Или возможно, но лучше использовать его с чем-то еще, например, с Java Script (jquery).
Будет ли это лучше?
Если да, то это совсем идеальный вариант для меня.

Хочу разрабатывать без перезагрузок страниц.
Подскажите лучший вариант.

Comment: Главное это как обратиться на Рельсах к элементу ДОМА по его id 
и узнать про методы типа click() как их искать в гугле а лучше ссылочку на такие методы.

Comment: Если по-простому (грубо, для чайников): рельсы -- это инструмент, с помощью которого генерируется "на лету" ХТМЛ, который, в свою очередь, отдаётся клиенту сервером (у вас -- webrick). Вы не можете обратится к ДОМу. Но вы можете написать (или сгенерировать динамически) Яваскрипт, который уже сделает, что надо. Рубин -- не замена Яваскрипту! Они нужны для разного. А вам не хватает самых начальных знаний о веб-технологиях. Начните, лучше с простого...

Comment: У вас совершенно нулевое понимание, как работают клиент-серверные приложения. На сервере работает Ruby с фреймворком, а вот на клиент уходит чистый HTML+CSS+JS. Вы не можете работать через Ruby с разметкой DOM, он только ее формирует и отдает. Это делается через тот же JQuery и другие библиотеки. В View пишется что-то вроде:

        <%= javascript_include_tag 'jquery' %>

И у вас к странице подтягивается Jquery.

Comment: Вообще я являюсь разработчиком на html+js+php.
И имею в арсенале пару серьезных игр, которые я разрабатывал методом МВЦ.

Почуствовал в Ruby больший потенциал и заточенность под это.
И решил перейти на него.
Сегодня первый день изучения, думаю, понятно почему у меня такие глупые вопросы.

Ruby формирует ДОМ на серве? Запутало это.
И получается что без JS не обойтись?
Меня очень сильно интересуют Контроллер.
Тот код, что ты написал, о-очень мало мне говорит.

Можешь дать ссылку на сайт, где бы описывалось то, что я ищу?
Был бы о-о-очень благодарен.

Comment: Грубо говоря: Рубин это альтернатива ПХП. Принципы те же.
____
http://railstutorial.ru/chapters/4_0/beginning